# Location not updating

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have succeed in making a map that shows nearby locations but its not updating the locations...Is there something wrong with the code..coz i m not finding anythin wrong...any help wud be appreciated..thanks in advance

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class NearbyPlacesActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    //instance variables for Marker icon drawable resources
    private int userIcon, foodIcon, drinkIcon, shopIcon, otherIcon;

    //the map
    private GoogleMap theMap;

    //location manager
    private LocationManager locMan;

    //user marker
    private Marker userMarker;

    //places of interest
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    //max
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;//most returned from google
    //marker options
    private MarkerOptions[] places;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_places);

        //get drawable IDs
        userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
        foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
        drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
        otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

        //find out if we already have it
        if(theMap==null){
            //get the map
            theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            //check in case map/ Google Play services not available
            if(theMap!=null){
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //create marker array
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];

            }

        }
    }

    //location listener functions

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "location changed");
        updatePlaces(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider disabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider enabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "status changed");
    }

    /*
     * update the place markers
     */
    private void updatePlaces(Location givenlocation){
        //get location manager
        double lat = givenlocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = givenlocation.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat+","+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //remove any existing marker
        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();
        //create and set marker properties
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("You are here")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
        .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        //move to location
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        //build places query string
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String encodedstr = URLEncoder.encode("food|bar|movie_theater|museum|bank");
        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=7000&sensor=true"+
                "&types="+encodedstr+
                "&key=AIzaSyBqDgqbxFenOtooTivY5YSsJ2JrwBK42hw";//ADD KEY

        //execute query
        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);       
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places

            //build result as string
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data

                    //HTTP Get receives URL string
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    //execute GET with Client - return response
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    //check response status
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //only carry on if response is OK
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //get response entity
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        //get input stream setup
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        //create reader
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        //use buffered reader to process
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
        //process data retrieved from doInBackground
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            //remove existing markers
            if(placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                    if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try {
                //parse JSON

                //create JSONObject, pass stinrg returned from doInBackground
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //get "results" array
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                //marker options for each place returned
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    //if any values are missing we won't show the marker
                    boolean missingValue=false;
                    LatLng placeLL=null;
                    String placeName="";
                    String vicinity="";
                    int currIcon = otherIcon;
                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        //get place at this index
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        //get location section
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location");
                        //read lat lng
                        placeLL = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")), 
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));  
                        //get types
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        //loop through types
                        for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType=types.get(t).toString();
                            //check for particular types - set icons
                            if(thisType.contains("food")){
                                currIcon = foodIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("bar")){
                                currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("movie_theater")){
                                currIcon = shopIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //vicinity
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        //name
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException jse){
                        Log.v("PLACES", "missing value");
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //if values missing we don't display
                    if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                    else
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(placeLL)
                    .title(placeName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                    .snippet(vicinity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=theMap.addMarker(places[p]);

            }

        }
    }   
}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(theMap!=null){
            //get location manager
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        updatePlaces(lastLoc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this class.

public class LocationListenerClass {
    private static LocationListenerClass instance;
    private static Context context;
    private LocationManager myLocationManager;
    private LocationListener myLocationListener;
    private static Double latitude = 0d;
    private static Double longitude = 0d;

```
public static LocationListenerClass getInstance(Context context) {
    LocationListenerClass.context = context;
    if (null == instance) {
        instance = new LocationListenerClass();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    try {
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                myLocationListener);

        Location location;
        location = myLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location == null) {
            myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                    myLocationListener);
            location = myLocationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (location != null) {
            try {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = latitude;
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " latitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = longitude;
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " longitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void removeLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        if (myLocationManager != null) {
            myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
            if (location != null) {
                Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = location.getLatitude();
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " latitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = location.getLongitude();
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " longitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can u plz explain wat changes are u doin...and what is wrong with my code...?